# why is glVertexAttribDivisor crashing?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, glsl, vertex

I am trying to render some trees with instancing. This is rather weird, but before sleeping yesterday night, I checked the code, and it was in a running state, when I got up this morning, it is crashing when I am calling `glVertexAttribDivisor` I haven't changed any code since yesterday.

Here is how I am sending data to GPU for instancing.

```
glGenBuffers(1, &iVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, iVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (ml_instance->i_positions.size()*sizeof(glm::vec4)) , NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, (ml_instance->i_positions.size()*sizeof(glm::vec4)), &ml_instance->i_positions[0]);
```

And then in vertex specification--

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, iVBO);
glVertexAttribPointer(i_positions, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(i_positions);
glVertexAttribDivisor(i_positions,1); // **THIS IS WHERE THE PROGRAM CRASHES**

glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0,TREES_INSTANCE_COUNT);
```

I have checked `ml_instance->i_positions`, it has all the data that needs to render.

I have checked the value of `i_positions` in vertex shader, it is the same as whatever I have defined there.

I am little out of ideas here, everything looks pretty much fine. What am I missing?

Comment: What platform are you running on? Are you using something like GLEW that gets function pointers for OpenGL entry points on startup? If that's the case, it's possible that `glVertexAttribDivisor` is a null function pointer.

Comment: yes, I do use GLEW, I am on win32 with VS2008.

Comment: the program did run after commenting out `glVertexAttribDivisor`, how can I check if glVertexAttribDivisor is NULL, and what should I do to avoid it? :)

Comment: Set a breakpoint before the call, start the program in debug mode, and hover the mouse over `glVertexAttribDivisor` once it stops on the breakpoint. It should be pretty clear if it's a valid address or null once you see the value.

Comment: `CXX0017: Error: symbol "glVertexAttribDivisor" not found` 
I guess you were right.

Comment: Ok. And if you do the same for other entry points, like `glVertexAttribPointer`, you see something different? `glVertexAttribDivisior` requires at least OpenGL 3.3. I suspect that either your system does not support 3.3, or more likely, your context is not set up for 3.3+. How you do that depends on what libraries/frameworks you use to set up your rendering. There's typically something in your setup code where you request the GL version you need. It could also be part of initializing GLEW. Or both.

Comment: well, as i said in the question, i ran the program yesterday and made sure that it was working perfectly fine. So, yes my system does support `glVertexAttribDivisor` and OpenGL 4.4. I am getting that information along with, vendor, renderer, and GLSL version. A simple restart did the trick for me.

Comment: So please delete the question if your solution was to reboot. It is sitting here pulling in  searches on glVertexAttribDivisor.

Comment: 4 years later, but I still have the same problem on a modern hardware (GL4.6-capable). I tried on a laptop with Nvidia 950m and Intel integrated graphics. It's OK on Nvidia, but the pointer is NULL when running on Intel. Another machine runs AMD adapter only and shows the same problem. So it looks like a ubiquitous bug in opengl drivers on in GLEW library.